# concept beind this version of fibonacci code in assembly

Tags: assembly, recursion

This is alternative version of fibonacci code in assembly used by my professor in class, it instead use a new formula.

```
f(n-2)/2 + f(n-1)*2

so the sequence is 1, 2, 4, 9, 20, 44, 98, 218
```

I just have a few things that confuse me.

1. what does jb and je means?
2. is one and two two local variables? what different part of equation do they take in the inputs in?
3. [ebp-4] and [ebp-8], are those registry? why are they choosed.

Please help me, I'm really lost the concept behind this code!

This is the code

```
TITLE Mobonacci 
.586
.MODEL FLAT, C
.code
    Mobonacci PROC
    ; will move n into EAX;

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov  eax, [ebp+8]

;   see if EAX is less than or equal to 1;

cmp  eax, 2
jb   one
je   two
ja   L1


; call the Mobonacci;

L1:
     sub esp, 8
     ; Mobo(n-1) * 2;
     sub eax, 1
     push eax
     call Mobonacci;
     mov ebx, eax
     pop eax


     ; times ebx by 2;
     shl ebx, 1
     mov [ebp-4], ebx


    ; Mobo(n-2)/2;
    sub eax, 1
    push eax
    call Mobonacci
    mov ebx, eax
    pop eax

    ; Divide ebx by 2;
    shr ebx, 1
    mov [ebp-8], ebx


    ; sum of two numbers;

    mov eax, 0
    add eax, [ebp-4]
    add eax, [ebp-8]

    ; Clean stack;
    mov  esp, ebp

    jmp ending


    ; Return 1;
    one:
       mov   eax, 1
       jmp   ending


    ; Return 2;
    two: 
       mov eax, 2
       jmp ending
    ; Return the value in eax;
    ending:
       pop ebp
       ret
    Mobonacci ENDP

    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) What do `jb` and `je` mean?

They are jumps in the x86 instruction set. `jb` is Jump Below, and `je` is Jump if Equal. They determine whether "below" or "equal" are true based upon the most recent operation that affects the x86 flags register. Or stated another way, if for example you did `cmp eax,ebx` (compare the `eax` and `ebx` registers), then `jb foo` right after that will jump to label `foo` if `eax` value is *below* the `ebx` value. And `je foo` would jump to label `foo` if the values were equal. Google "x86 jump instructions" for more details.

> 2) Are `one` and `two` two local variables? What different part of
>   equation do they take in the inputs in?

Not variables. They are labels which indicate places that can be jumped to from other places in the code. If you combine this knowledge with the answer to question #1, the code compares `eax` with `2` (`cmp eax,2`) and `jb one` jumps to label `one` if `eax` is less than `2` (it's value is probably 1), and `je two` jumps to label `two` if the value of `eax` is equal to `2`. Finally, `ja L1` jumps to label `L1` if the value of `eax` is *above* the value 2. Note that since the very next instruction has label `L1`, this has no functional effect.

> 3) `[ebp-4]` and `[ebp-8]`, are those registry? Why are they chosen?

The `ebp` is the Base Pointer register in the x86 architecture. It would normally contain an address. The references `[ebp-4]` and `[ebp-8]` refer to values which are at locations `ebp-4` and `ebp-8` in memory (the value of that address reduced by 4 and reduced by 8). Google "x86 stack frame" for details on why this is done this way.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of ebp is optional. The code could have used

```
Mobonacci PROC
        sub     esp,8          ;allocate space for 2 integers
        mov     eax,[esp+12]   ;get parameter
;       ...
        mov     [esp+4],ebx    ;instead of [ebp-4]
;       ...
        mov     [esp+0],ebx    ;instead of [ebp-8]
;       ...
ending:
        add     esp,8          ;restore esp
        ret
Mobonacci ENDP
```